# Unable to set header field "apns-push-type" in Apple Push Notification in javapns

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, javapns, javaapns

I have a legacy code which send notifications to iOS.

```
public List<NotificationResponse> sendNotifications(Constants.App app, List<String> deviceTokens, String payload,
        List<String> userId, String sender, String appKey) {
    List<NotificationResponse> response = new ArrayList<NotificationResponse>();
    String keystore = serviceKeyMap.get(app).getApiServiceKey();
    String password = serviceKeyMap.get(app).getPassword();
    String toUser = StringUtils.EMPTY;
    Integer appId = NotificationHistoryHelper.getAppMap().get(appKey);
    if (!CollectionUtils.isEmpty(userId)) {
        toUser = userId.get(0);
    }
    try {
        LOGGER.info("Multicasting payload: {} to devices: {}", new Object[] { payload, deviceTokens });
        ApnsService service;
        ApnsServiceBuilder serviceBuilder = APNS.newService().withCert(keystore, password)
                .withProductionDestination();
        if (deviceTokens.size() == 1) {
            serviceBuilder.withDelegate(new ApnsDelegateImpl(deviceTokens.get(0), payload,
                    notificationHistoryService, toUser, sender, appId));
        }
        service = serviceBuilder.build();
        service.push(deviceTokens, payload);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOGGER.error("Exception while sending notification to multiple devices", e);
    }
    return response;
}
```

Everything is working as expected. Today, as part of an enhancement, I need to send "apns-push-type" in the http header, which is required by iOS 13+.

[Apple Developer Document link for "apns-push-type"](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/setting_up_a_remote_notification_server/sending_notification_requests_to_apns?language=objc)

I am unable to find any option (method, class, etc.) to set http header information using apns library.

Below is the classpath entry in my project for the apns jar,

```
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/apns-1.0.0.Beta6.jar"/>
```

Please help me in this. I have scoured the internet, stackoverflow, but didn't find any clues.

Comment: Are you able to send apns-push-type in header?

Comment: @Sandippatil How to add header? Any sample code?

Comment: @Rishav Did you found solution for it?

Comment: @Sandippatil the apns library used in my project was not actively maintained (https://github.com/notnoop/java-apns). It was last maintained in October 2016.

Comment: @pankaj, I chose a new library to solve my problem, and changed my code accordingly. (https://github.com/jchambers/pushy)